# Identifier of an entity was altered from one one to another

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have an entity in spring boot application having composite pk( long num, Date date, String typ)
When I fetch one entity, change the date and save it again, getting this error:

> identifier of entity was altered from entityPk(num=1234567,
> date=2023-02-15 09:00:00, typ="12") to  entityPk(num=1356789,
> date=2023-02-15 09:00:00, typ="12")

Didn't get an idea to get rid of rid error

Comment: Please add more details like: source code or the entity, the code snippet where you are modifying and saving it, the error message you got.

Comment: you modify pk.

just add another one. And delete old.

Or you can create modify query like:  Update someEntite set someDate = ? where pkColumns = ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to change a primary key, by definition. A primary key is something that should never change.
You'll have to run a native query for doing this, or create the entity with the new id and migrate associations to that new entity then.